# Wrong behaviour of wrapfigure environment when using "placement = outer"

Tags: koma-script, wrapfigure

I'm trying to place some pictures inside my text using the [wrapfig package of Donald Arseneau](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig) with [KOMAscript of Markus Kohm](http://www.komascript.de/). The intention is to place the pictures partly in the margin area at the outer side of a twosided document.

According to the package documentation I have to set the `placement` parameter value to the capital letter `O` to gain *the outside edge–far from the binding*, and the `overhang` parameter to a value of *how much the figure should hang out into the margin*.

That's what I have done in the attached minimum working example. As you can see in the attached picture, this works fine on odd pages, but the picture is misplaced on even pages.

Additional it seems that the `overhang` parameter -- different from the manual's description -- specifies the value how much the figure should hang into the **text** (not the margin).

Is it my fault, or a bug in the package?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello, World!}
\Blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{qr}
\end{wrapfigure}
\Blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{qr}
\end{wrapfigure}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can make out that you have seen the manual, but still have a look at this:

[image]

Now in this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{1cm}
```

you haven't specified the `overhang` but the width as `1cm` and putting a picture of `width=3cm`.

Let us correct it:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{O}[1cm]{3cm}
```

Here `overhang` is `1cm` and total width is `3cm`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello, World!}
\Blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}[1cm]{3cm}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\Blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}[1cm]{3cm}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
\end{wrapfigure}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damned, that is awkward :-( Thanks!

Comment: @ChristophJüngling It's natural and happens to all of us :-)